# PHP Menu item breaks all following menu items

Tags: php, menu, include

The menus are all separated into PHP includes and called in the main index.php file. The issue is all of the menu items work fine until a specific menu item. At which point that linked page and all of the following links after it in the menu stop functioning without any sort of inspector error. The problem page is titled eva.php. From what I can tell the original creator of the site has all of the pages are being called correctly, but I'm fairly new to PHP so forgive any ignorance on my part.

Index File:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php require_once('inc/meta.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/script.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/styles.php'); ?>

</head>
<body>

<div id="slidemenu" class="scrollable closed">
    <ul id="menuAll">
        <h2>Applications</h2>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuCabinetsCounters">Furniture, Cabinet &amp; Countertop Substrates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuEngineeredFlooring">Engineered Flooring Substrates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuFlooringFurnitureCabinetsCounters">Flooring, Furniture, Cabinet &amp; Countertop Laminates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuMouldingMillwork">Molding &amp; Millwork</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuDoorsWindows">Doors &amp; Windows</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuFraming">Framing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuSheathing">Sheathing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuRoofing">Roofing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuInsulation">Insulation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="menuDecks">Decks, Porches, Cladding &amp; Fences</a></li>
        <h2>More</h2>
        <li><a href="#page-sustainability">Sustainability</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-video2">Formaldehyde in Construction Video</a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-framing.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-cabinets-counters.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-flooring-furniture-cabinets-counters.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-doors-windows.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-furniture.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-sheathing.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-roofing.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-insulation.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-moulding-millwork.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-engineered-flooring.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-locations.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('inc/menu-decks.php'); ?>
</div>   
<div data-role="page" id="main_page" data-theme="a"> 
    <div data-role="header"> <a href="#"class="menuBtn">☰</a>
</div> 
</div>

<?php require_once('inc/page-other.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-urea-formaldehyde.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-melamine-formaldehyde-powder.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-melamine-urea-formaldehyde.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-resorcinol-formaldehyde.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-phenol-resorcinol-formaldehyde.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-emulsion-polymerized-isocyanate.php'); ?> 
<?php require_once('inc/page-polyvinyl-acetate.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-polyurethane-dispersions.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-hot-melts.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-casein-glues.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-phenol-formaldehyde.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-phenol-formaldehyde-adhesive.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-phenol-formaldehyde-powder.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-phenol-resorcinol-based-resins.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-wax-emulsions.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-melamine-urea-phenol-formaldehyde.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-pva-adhesives.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-melamine-based-resins.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-melamine-resorcinol-based-resins.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-resorcinol-based-resins.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-fentak.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-osb-specialized.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-phenolic-resins.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-amino-resins.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-wood.php'); ?> 
<?php require_once('inc/page-eva.php'); ?> <-- PROBLEM PAGE

<?php require_once('inc/page-lvl-ready.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-lvl-reactor.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-lvl-in-plant.php'); ?>

<?php require_once('inc/page-sustainability.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-video1.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-video2.php'); ?>

<?php require_once('inc/page-na.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-sa.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-apac.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc/page-europe.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Menu Include:

```
<ul id="menuFlooringFurnitureCabinetsCounters">
    <h2>Flooring, Furniture, Cabinet &amp; Countertop Laminates</h2>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="img/thumb/particleboard.jpg" width="70" height="70" />
        <h3>Countertop Laminates</h3></a>
        <ul>
        <h4>Countertop Laminates</h4>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-urea-formaldehyde">Urea Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-melamine-formaldehyde-powder">Melamine Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-melamine-urea-formaldehyde">Melamine-Urea Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-polyvinyl-acetate">Polyvinyl Acetate Adhesives</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-eva">Ethylene Vinyl Acetate Adhesives</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-fentak">Fentak Additives</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="img/thumb/mdf.jpg" width="70" height="70" />
        <h3>Cabinet Laminates</h3></a>
        <ul>
        <h4>Cabinet Laminates</h4>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-fentak">Fentak Additives</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-urea-formaldehyde">Urea Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-melamine-urea-formaldehyde">Melamine-urea Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-melamine-formaldehyde-powder">Melamine Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-polyvinyl-acetate">Polyvinyl Acetate Adhesives</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-eva">Ethylene Vinyl Acetate Adhesives</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>


    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="img/thumb/plywood.jpg" width="70" height="70" />
        <h3>Flooring Laminates</h3></a>
        <ul>
        <h4>Flooring Laminates</h4>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-fentak">Fentak Additives</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-urea-formaldehyde">Urea Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-melamine-urea-formaldehyde">Melamine-urea Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-melamine-formaldehyde-powder">Melamine Formaldehyde Resins</a></li>
            <li><a data-prefetch href="#page-pva-adhesives">Polyvinyl Acetate Adhesives</a></li>
        </ul>


    </li>

  </ul>
```

Eva Page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-eva" data-theme="a" data-cache="never">
    <div data-role="header"> <a href="#"class="menuBtn">☰</a>
</div>
    <div data-role="content" id="eva-ethylene-vinyl-acetate">
        <div class="form"></div><div class="pad">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Q: what do you mean when saying "At which point it breaks that link and all following" ? Q: did you put the break line on purpose ? Q: can it be a css problem ? Q: have you tried and clean spaces between div in eva.php ?

Comment: @OldPadawan Ah, sorry. I'll clarify above for future readers too. What I mean by that is that menu item and all other menu items don't load their requested pages. A: I wasn't the original creator of this site, so I wasn't responsible for the break line. A: I wouldn't assume that the CSS is the issue due to the other menu items all live off of the same CSS and they work before it hits the EVA.php page. A: I have not, but I will give that a shot.

Comment: another Q: how's generated eva.php ? is it only html ? also, if you have some php in pages, include this at the very top (but session) : error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: A: Eva.php is a static php file living in the includes folder of the server. From what I can see there is no dynamic creation of it. From what I can tell it's only HTML which confused me too since it's saved as a php format. A: Dropped it in. No errors are being displayed.

Comment: could you give hints about the css used ? if too long or can't be shorten, maybe posted on a sharing-system ?